# Stop Excel from Combining Windows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

If I open up two different Excel files, even though there's two elements in the taskbar, I can't view both of them at the same time...

How do I stop Excel from combining Windows?

Comment: *I can't view both of them at the same time...* It's because you use one Excel instance. *How do I stop Excel from combining Windows?* Open Excel. Open first file in it. Then open another Excel instance. Then open next file in it. Now you can view both files (tile, cascade, etc.)

Comment: @Akina It won't let me open more than one Excel instance. Whenever I open multiple files, it always gets lumped into one window. That's the problem...

Comment: You open FILE. I have said you must open next Excel: *Open Excel.* Start-Programs-MSOffice-Excel *Open first file in it.* In Excel - File-Open/Recent *Then open another Excel instance.* Start-Programs-MSOffice-Excel *Then open next file in it.* In newly opened clear Excel window - File-Open/Recent

Comment: @Akina you should have said that from the start

Comment: @BugWhisperer, could you share the Screen Shot with us, for better understanding !!

Comment: @RajeshS its been solved. but i wish there was a better way to keep the windows separated other than having to launch excel through the start menu and then open the file in excel. is there a different way to do it?

Comment: @BugWhisperer,, if you share the Screen Shot then I can try something !!

Comment: @RajeshS im extremely busy at the moment, but i will post a screenshot soon and i will message you when i do!! thanks <333